# How to use Label instead of Double when adding a value in TChart Lazarus

Tags: pascal, lazarus

When using TChart component, let say adding one bar series, how to change the value of the x axis using label instead of Double?

Currently I can only using addXY in bar series, with two numbers.
Is it possible to add like (Apple, 1000), (Orange, 400), (Banana, 10)?
Currently I am just using an index and add the fruit name as the label. I want to put the label not on the bar, but exactly in the x axis.

How to do such thing using TChart in Lazarus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the BarSeries' ListSource to the Marks.Source of the BottomAxis and set Marks.Style to smsLabel. Can only be done at runtime, and "smsLabel" requires unit TAChartUtils in the "uses" clause.

```
uses
  TAChartUtils;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1Barseries1.AddXY(1, 1000, 'Apple');
  Chart1BarSeries1.AddXY(2, 400, 'Orange');
  Chart1BarSeries1.AddXY(3, 10, 'Banana');
  Chart1.BottomAxis.Marks.Source := Chart1BarSeries1.listSource;  // <---
  Chart1.BottomAxis.Marks.Style := smsLabel;                      // <---
end;
```

Comment: Would you mind providing a simple sample? I tried but still not working.


  barSeries.ListSource.Assign(chart1.BottomAxis.Marks.Source);
  barSeries.Marks.Style := smsLabel;

It said that you cannot assign a TListChartSource to a TListChartSource.